# Error About Number of Elements In For-Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, element

Here is my code:

```
%Initial Conditions:

y(1)=1;
Dy(1)=0;
DDy(1)=0;
t(1)=0;

%Parameters:
dt = 0.1;
nsteps =10/dt;

for i=1:nsteps
    t(i+1) = t(i) + dt;
    DDy(i+1) = 12*t.*y(i) + (18*t.^2 - 6).*(y(i).^2).*Dy(i);
    Dy(i+1) = Dy(i) + DDy(i)*dt;
    y(i+1) = y(i) + Dy(i+1)*dt;
end
```

And here is the error message:

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of
elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in euler_croemer_de (line 20)
    DDy(i+1) = 12*t.*y(i) + (18*t.^2 -
    6).*(y(i).^2).*Dy(i);

---

I have tried searching on the internet, that I might resolve the issue myself. However, I honestly couldn't find anything helpful.

I would appreciate someones help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
DDy(i+1) = 12*t.*y(i) + (18*t.^2 - 6).*(y(i).^2).*Dy(i);
```

`t` contains `i+1` elements, so the right-hand side is a vector of length `i+1`. However, the left-hand side refers to a single value, namely one entry of `DDy`. So you are trying to assign a vector to a single entry of `DDy`. Hence the error.

Maybe you mean `t(i+1)` instead of `t` on that line?

Comment: Oh, so the error was that I neglected to index the vector t in my for loop?

Comment: @Mack It depends on what you intended to do. But certainly, if you index the vector `t` the error will disappear